# Using Apache CXF wsdl to javascript client

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, wsdl

My situation is: I have a wsdl from a webservice (soap). With the Apache CXF i managed to geneate a client. That gives me a huge .js file, in theory a usable client to access from javascript and call the services.

The problem is: There is no information about how to use this client, neither which methods call to start a SOAP process.

If anyone has experience with this, or knows how to initiate the process, or even know any handfull tool to consume Soap based webservices from javascript would be really nice!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Apache CXF has a sample about js client. You can check it out.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/javascript-client-samples.html

If you need help specific to your webservice, then share its WSDL.